# Header Issue when knitting with jpg image

Tags: r, markdown

I am new to markdown and have to generate a weekly report with the proper header including a jpg image. I have the following yaml

```
---
title: "My Title"
author: "Author Name"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
header-includes:
    - \usepackage{setspace}\doublespacing
    - \usepackage{float}
    - \usepackage{graphicx}
    - \usepackage{fancyhdr}
    - \pagestyle{fancy}
    - \pretitle{\begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=2in]{picture.jpg}}
    - \posttitle{\end[center]}
    
mainfont: Calibri
output: 
  pdf_document:
      latex_engine: xelatex
---
```

Company policy states that all documents have to be in Calibri(I know) which was the main issue prior to this.
When I go to knit I get this error

```
Error in yaml::yaml.load(..., eval.expr = TRUE) : 
  Scanner error: while scanning a simple key at line 11, column 5 could not find expected ':' at line 12, column 5
Calls: <Anonymous> ... parse_yaml_front_matter -> yaml_load -> <Anonymous>
Execution halted
```

Any help on a resolution is much appreciated.

Comment: `\end[center]`  you have `[]` when you meant `{}`

Comment: Good catch! Thanks, unfortunately this didn't solve my issue.

Comment: it's moaning about line 11 the `\includegraphics` you could presumably put it on the line above, although yaml+markdown syntax is not really on topic here.

Comment: Ah, too true. Thanks for you help anyways, this was more of a shot in the dark anyways.